# Reproject features with geotools

Tags: java, geotools

is there a way to reproject a feature collection into a new one with another coordinate reference system? I am trying to achieve this by using geotools's reprojector:

```
SimpleFeatureSource featureSource = ...
SimpleFeatureCollection sfc = new ReprojectingFeatureCollection(featureSource.getFeatures(),
    org.geotools.referencing.CRS.decode("EPSG:4326"));
```

`sfc` presents another schema's `CRS` but its geometries looks the same before reprojecting. What am I missing? Do I have to manually create a new geometry with desired `CRS` and coordinates for each geometry in featureSource or geotools offer a more elegant and efficient way to do this? I am using geotools version 17.2.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This code works for me:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, NoSuchAuthorityCodeException, FactoryException {
     if(args.length==0) {
       System.err.println("usage: Reprojector shapefile.shp");
       System.exit(1);
     }
     FileDataStore ds = FileDataStoreFinder.getDataStore(new File(args[0]));
     SimpleFeatureCollection features = ds.getFeatureSource().getFeatures();
     try(SimpleFeatureIterator itr=features.features()){
       int count=0;
       while(itr.hasNext()&&count++<10) {
         System.out.println(((Geometry) itr.next().getDefaultGeometry()).getCentroid());
       }
     }
     System.out.println("");
     ReprojectingFeatureCollection rfc = new ReprojectingFeatureCollection(features, CRS.decode("epsg:3875"));
     try(SimpleFeatureIterator itr=rfc.features()){
       int count=0;
       while(itr.hasNext()&&count++<10) {
         System.out.println(((Geometry) itr.next().getDefaultGeometry()).getCentroid());
       }
     }
  }
```

giving this output:

```
POINT (-69.97420075028728 12.516935269076281)
POINT (66.00844744953935 33.836266910437075)

POINT (7865991.086526802 4801048.897930129)
POINT (4827402.208410819 25805775.61452194)
```

Comment: Hello, I want to reproject EPSG:32632 features in EPSG:4326. As I run your code I obtain this point,
POINT (626913.7451504259 5058702.588350934)
correspond to this one:
POINT (45.67025422985437 10.629381224435772)
I think that point should looks like this:
POINT (10.629381224435772 45.67025422985437)
Am I wrong?

Comment: that is correct - see http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/referencing/order.html

Comment: That was. Hours wasted because I forgot a system property.. Could be useful to mention that system property directly in your answer. I'll accept it.

Comment: that system property is only relevant if you have swapped your axes by mistake in general learn to like lat,lon :-)

Comment: Doesn't changing the wrapped _Geometries_ in a collection work as well? So you don't have the need to create a new collection nor layer.

Comment: No, there are no features in the collection until you have iterated through it, and there are none when you finish iterating. That is why we can handle millions of features.