# Formula for transforming from EPSG:4326 to EPSG:3003 or EPSG:3004

Tags: convert, epsg, mathematics

This system is used in Italy.
I came across [this](https://www.matematicamente.it/magazine/20settembre2013/190-Mazzucato-Coordinate-geografiche-gaussiane.pdf):

It says that lambda zero is 9° if it's to epsg:3003 otherwise if it's to epsg:3004 it's 15°
[image]

I came up with this Java code, but the result is wrong:

```
public static Posizione fromGeo2MonteMario(Posizione from, String srid)
{
    double fi = from.getLatitude();
    double la = from.getLongitude();
    double b = la - (srid.equals("EPSG:3003") ? 9d : 15d);
    fi = convert2Rad(fi);
    la = convert2Rad(la);
    b = convert2Rad(b);
    double w = Math.sqrt(1 + (0.0067681702 * Math.pow(Math.cos(fi),2)) );
    double a = Math.atan( Math.tan(fi) / Math.cos(w * b));
    double v = Math.sqrt(1 + (0.0067681702 * Math.pow(Math.cos(a),2)) );
    double y = 6397376.633 * asinh( Math.cos(a) * Math.tan(b) / v);

    Posizione to = new Posizione();
    to.setNorth( (111092.08210 * a) - (16100.59187 * Math.sin(2*a)) + (16.96942 * Math.sin(4*a)) - (0.02226 * Math.sin(6*a)) );
    to.setEast( y + 500000);

    return to;
}

public static double asinh(double x)
{
    return Math.log(x + Math.sqrt(x*x + 1.0));
}

public static double convert2Rad(double degAngle)
{
    return degAngle * Math.PI / 180;
}
```

For example, latitude 42 and longitude 11, is EPSG:3003 so it should be around: East: 1665646.4 North: 4651793.5
[You can test it here (or check the example in the pdf)](http://geoportale.regione.emilia-romagna.it/it/services/servizi-OGC/servizio-di-conversione)

Comment: My code review :) No source for convert2Rad(). But let's say, it's OK. You convert from.getLatitude(),getLongitude() to radians, so I assume underlying units in Posizione are degrees. Then you do math in radians and pass them to methods setLongitude()/setLatitude() without converting to degrees.

Comment: Latitude and Longitude are usually expressed in degree (in google map for example). You have right, the output value are not in degree, but just because I was lazy to refine the method. I will edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you're experiencing some sort of localization issues with those particular coordinate systems in Italy, but maybe you should look into [GeoTools](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide), and in particular [reprojecting geometries](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/geometry/geometrycrs.html).  They provide a [maven repo](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/build/maven/index.html) as well.  I have never used this but it appears to support coordinate systems registered with the EPSG, so it would probably work in this case?

Also, see this post on [reprojecting geometries with GeoTools](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/255930/reproject-features-with-geotools).

Comment: I tried it, but I've to use java 6, and I get various errors with the old version 10 of GeoTools

Comment: Ok, I got it. I mixed the jts.jar from the 18.2 library with the 10.8 library. I used ten files .jar (6MB) to make a simple math operation. I up-voted you, but would be nice do the math in the old style, without libraries.